# Incorrect number of arguments for type List<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JSONObject, JSONArray>

Tags: java, json, collections

I have imported java.util.List interface.
trying to create a function as follow:

```
public List<JSONObject,JSONArray> getDetail(String s)
```

But it shows error as
"Incorrect number of arguments for type List; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <JSONObject, JSONArray>"
I have gone through many articles but they said ,import java.util.List instead java.awt.List but i already imported that.
Can anyone help here what i am missing here  ?

Comment: Even I don't understand what you mean by `List<JSONObject, JSONArray>`, let alone the compiler...

Comment: `java.util.List` is made to be a list of one kind of elements, like a list of strings. `List<JSONObject,JSONArray>` wants the list to be of 2 kinds of elements, and `java.util.List` has no such concept. What are you trying to store in the list?

Comment: what are you trying is not valid. i guess you want to return json consisting of array inside it. Create array object like variable in main object  and return the main object

Comment: Do you mean a list that can contain either of the two types? If so you need to settle for a common super type (might as well be just `Object`) or interface and when getting the elements back you need to test them using `instanceOf` or similar.

Comment: You are trying to have a list of two different types, I mean the declaration is not valid at all. The error is expected. Are you sure what you want to do ?

Comment: what i want to do is , if there is any error then it should return jsonobject else return jsonarray that contain details. List<Object,Object> is also not working for me.

Comment: Java doesn't have feature of return two types, you can do other way round.

Comment: @Neha *"should return jsonobject else return jsonarray"* Those are singular words, so if you want to return one `JSONObject` *or* one `JSONArray`, specify the return type as `Object`. If you did in fact want to return many of either or both, specify the return type as `List<Object>`. *Document* that return value will only be one of the two, not any kind of object.

Comment: @Andreas, i unserstand you way,its pretty what i m looking for but how do i retrun list ? e.g.return new List<JSONObjectName>(); ?

Comment: As other people said, a Java List can only be parameterized with one parameter, not two. You can have a `List<JSONObject>` or a `List<JSONArray>`, but not both at the same time. If you want to store both types of objects in the same list, you can create a List parameterized with a common superclass. Anyway, what you're trying to do is strange (return one type or the other based on some condition), and I think there is a problem in the way you're thinking about your problem. Try to explain why you want to do so, and maybe post some code.

Comment: Make return type `Object`, then it can be `List<JSONObjectName>` or `JSONObjectName[]` or `JSONObjectName` or `ErrorDetail` or `ErrorDetail[]` or `List<ErrorDetail>` or *whatever* the method chooses to actually return.

Comment: Or you can just return map that contain all the data,
`public Map<String,Object> getDetail(String s){
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        //Case 1
        map.put("object",new JSONObject());
        map.put("array", null);

        //Case 2
        map.put("object",null);
        map.put("array",new JSONArray());
        
        return map;
    }`

Comment: [What is an array?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NptnmWvkbTw). Let's start with the basics and we will move to collections later.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, Making Objet as return type and then checking as jsonobject or array gives me solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem here. This is what you are doing. Let's understand this by the below example.

[image]

This is the same error you are getting at compile time. So basically you are doing something wrong with the List. List can only store single elements but you are putting 2 elements (key & value). So Map is the data structure to store this kind of value. Below screenshot is your answer. Hope this is clear to you now.

[image]